# Understanding the definition of a random variable

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables

I'm working through a math stats book on my own (I've always wanted to learn it), but I'm getting confused about the definition of a random variable.  The book says that a random variable is a function from the state space $\Omega$ into some space $T$.  I understand this in terms of some simple examples: take a finite state space where each event has a probability.  Then, given some $X$, we can easily compute $E(X)$ by mapping each event in $\Omega$ to $X(\omega)$ and so on.

But, here's my problem: we also talk about "Normal random variables" or "Cauchy random variables" or ...  I having a hard time connecting those random variables to the functional definition.  What is the state space $\Omega$?  My first guess would be $\Omega=\mathbb{R}$, but that doesn't seem right because $P(\Omega)=1$ and equal length intervals should have equal probability, right?  That doesn't work if $\Omega=\mathbb{R}$ though...

Comment: Why should equal length intervals have the same probability? In the discrete case you are probably comfortable with points having unequal probabilities.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First of all, a random variable is usually defined as a function $X: \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$. So for any possible event in the state space $\omega \in \Omega$, the random variable $X(\omega)$ assigns a real number to that event.

Strictly speaking, probabilities are defined for special sets of events in $\Omega$. They are not defined on the target space $\mathbb{R}$. So if we're being precise, it doesn't makes sense to ask "what is the probability of $X = 3$?" Instead, we should be asking "what is the probability of the *set of events corresponding to* $X=3$?"

**But, there's a catch.** Random variables are not just any old functions. They are **measurable** functions from $\Omega \to \mathbb{R}$. This means that any set of values in the target space $\mathbb{R}$ corresponds to some set of events in $\Omega$, for which a probability has been defined. Therefore, because of this fact we can cut corners and refer to "the probability of $X = 3$," even though it doesn't *exactly* make sense.

Which brings us to your question. When we speak of "Normal" or "Cauchy" random variables, we are describing **how** the random variables assign probabilities to events in the state space $\Omega$. We are **not** actually describing the state space itself. When we say that, for a Normal r.v. $X$ that $P(X \leq 1) = 0.84$, we are really saying that "the probability of all events $\omega$ that $X$ maps to a real number $\leq$ 1 is equal to 0.84." But these events themselves can be anything.

So in short, the answer is: **it depends.**

Comment: Ah, ok, that makes sense.  Thanks!